# Modifying Latitude and Longitude Arrays in Xarray

Tags: netcdf, python-xarray

**I am trying to match the dimensions and coordinates of my target dataset variables :**
[image: Target Dataset]

**From a source dataset which currently looks like this:**
[image: Source Dataset]

1. How do I add 'time' as a dimension and also as a coordinate to 'time' itself as it is in source dataset?
2. I am not able to understand how to generate  'lat' or 'lon' variables which have both coordinates 'east_west' and 'north_south'? The 'lat' ideally contains only 'north_south' values and 'lon' should contain only 'east_west'. But, I need to match it to the source.

I am able to match the coordinates for rest of the variables but I am not able to do it for lat,lon and time.

Comment: You may be unable to match the dimensions and coordinates to your target data dataset because both datasets doesn't seem to match at all. They don't match along the lat,lon, dimensions. You might have to regrid your data to match with your your traget data. You can easily do this in `cdo`.

Comment: Thank you. I will explore `cdo` to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the time dimensions with `.squeeze(dim="time")`, this should turn it into a scalar coordinate like in your target dataset.
https://xarray.pydata.org/en/v0.7.2/generated/xarray.Dataset.squeeze.html

Your latitude and longitude coordinates don't seem to be well formed: you probably want to get rid of all those `nan`s, with e.g.:

```py
ds = ds.where(ds["lat"].notnull())
```

And what do you mean with "match to the source"? If you want to have the data at the same coordinates, you'll likely have to interpolate. Your target dataset is a good bit bigger than the source, and I'm guessing cell sizes differ as well.

You could have a try with `reindex_like`, and use `method="nearest"`:
https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.reindex_like.html

Comment: Thank you. But I need to do the opposite, I need to add the  "NANs" to my source. I need not to match the data at all. I just need the coordinates and dimension "arrangement" (for time, lat and lon) like in the 2nd dataset.  I hope I am clear on this.